# Serving video to iOS devices using the Apache/PHP server included with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, apache, ios, postgresql, video

I am developing a system in which a server will serve a video to a device (iDevice or otherwise) and then ask the user to rate the video. I had decided to use PostgreSQL for my database, and let it install an Apache and PHP server to work against (as found here http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload).

It seems, however, that this server isn't configured quite like a typical Apache/PHP install. When an iDevice attempts to download a video from the server, the iDevice gives this error:

> Cannot play movie—The server is not correctly configured

I've done some research, and learned that iDevices require byte-range request functionality, so I checked my server's access logs and found this:

> xx.xx.xx.xx - - [08/Mar/2011:11:45:56 -0700] "GET temp.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 2
>   xx.xx.xx.xx - - [08/Mar/2011:11:45:56 -0700] "GET temp.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 17760579

(where "17760579" was the exact size in bytes of the particular file)
They should look something like this:

> xx.xx.xx.xx - - [07/Mar/2011:18:04:11 -0700] "GET temp.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 2
>   xx.xx.xx.xx - - [07/Mar/2011:18:04:11 -0700] "GET temp.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 25947357
>   xx.xx.xx.xx - - [07/Mar/2011:18:04:11 -0700] "GET temp.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 60637
>   xx.xx.xx.xx - - [07/Mar/2011:18:04:11 -0700] "GET temp.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 25880928

So, I know that my server isn't dealing with some byte-range requests properly. However, using **curl** to check for this functionality returns a proper result:

```
curl --range 0-99 http://url/temp.mp4 -o /dev/null
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   100    0   100    0     0   8574      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10000
```

I've ensured that the video MIME types are properly configured.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Something, somewhere, is misconfigured in this server.

Update:
Here are appropriate version numbers:

> Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix)
>   Server built:   Oct  7 2010 00:26:09
>   PHP version 5.3.3
>   PostgreSQL 9.0.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin

Comment: PostgreSQL does not include an Apache server, or PHP.

Comment: Check this site—integrated packages for most platforms: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

Comment: @whiteXbread, EnterpriseDB's packaging is not the same as upstream PostgreSQL. If you're asking questions about their offering, you need to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to fix this problem. I had initially used the PostgreSQL/Apache/PHP install package found at the site in my comment on the question because it was a way to install all three and make sure they worked without hassle. Obviously, since the resulting server didn't provide the functionality I needed, I had the option of installing everything from scratch. I used the instructions found [here](http://bit.ly/dI9dlP) to achieve this result. The instructions are a bit out of date, but the process worked.

Answer (score 0):

iOS Devices use a streaming service called "HTTP Live Streaming", it was developed when apple released the Quicktime Streaming Server (QSS).

Unless your server is configured to do live streaming, your videos will simply download, and then play. Not play on demand.

Another option is RTSP streaming, but I'm not sure how the rating system comes into play with all of this. That sounds like a job for an iPhone / iOS app.

Comment: In this application, I am in fact interested in the device downloading the video.  iOS devices do not support RTSP (see here http://bit.ly/fNTum3).  The reason I am not making an app for these devices is that I plan, eventually, on extending it to other mobile devices that support HTML5 video tags.

Answer (score 0):

Apache needs mod_h264 installed and enabled to properly handle mp4's with the byte range requests. Have you checked for the presence of this mod?

Comment: Thanks for your answer—the machine I wrote this question about is long gone. However, I'm looking through the `httpd.conf` of a working apache install and not seeing the mod installed.